# Permission issue while reading files from opencpu server

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, opencpu, apparmor

when trying to read files deployed in my ec2 instance while running my opencpu app I get file connection error. The same works with the single user version on rstudio server.

I checked the logs in /var/log/kern.log and found this

```
 apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="opencpu-exec" name="<path to my file>" pid=1444 comm="apache2" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=33 ouid=1000
```

What does this mean? I had set chmod 777 to all the files from where I should read the data. How should I get my app to read these files?

EDIT: I added /** r to my /etc/apparmor.d/opencpu.d/custom file. Still not able to read my csv files. but the kern.log file looks like this

```
apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=2392 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

I cross checked my file paths and verified that the files are indeed present from where I have to read them.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file stored in directory where apache (`www-data`) is allowed to read?